# Get context in onBindViewHolder in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android

I'm trying to create checkboxes programatically in the RecyclerViewAdapter but I'm not sure how to pass the context in the onBindViewHolder. Also worth noting I'm using 4 different ViewHolders classes.

This is the ViewHolder class where I want to add the checkboxes, this code is inside the `onBindViewHolder`

```
ViewHolderMulChoice viewHolderMulChoice = (ViewHolderMulChoice) holder;
viewHolderMulChoice.questionNumber.setText((position + 1) + ")");
viewHolderMulChoice.questionTitle.setText(current.getQuestion());
viewHolderMulChoice.questionInstructions.setText(current.getInstruction());
if (current.getOptional() == 1) {
    viewHolderMulChoice.questionOptional.setText("*");
} else {
    viewHolderMulChoice.questionOptional.setText("");
}

List<SurveyQuestionOptions> options = current.getSurvey_question_option();
for (SurveyQuestionOptions option: options) {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(//context goes here);
    checkBox.setText(option.getOption());
    viewHolderMulChoice.options.addView(checkBox);
}
```

Comment: Pass it as an argument to your adapter or get it from `yourViewHolder.itemView.getContext()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to take context as a constructor param. every view has reference to context

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int i) {
     Context context = holder.itemview.getContext();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass the `Context` as a **Constructor parameter** to your Adapter and then you can access it.

Like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private String[] mDataset;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get [**`Context`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context) at first

> Interface to global information about an application environment.
>   This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the
>   Android system.

```
    private Context context;  

   // Adapter
    public YourAdapter(Context context,..) {  
       this.context = context;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why not pass the context by adapter constructor:**

**In your adapter:**

```
class YourAdapter extends ......{

private Context context;
.....
.....

public YourAdapter(................., Context context){

....
...
this.context = context;
}

}
```

**When you create the adapter in your activity:**

```
YourAdapter adapter  = new YourAdapter(..............., YourActivity.this);
```